# Delete Permission Deny To Everyone , but Now they are unable to Modify Files

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have Deny the permission of delete to Everyone , but after this every one is unable to save their documents. I am using windows server 2003 , I have changed the permission for Creator Owner to modify but still The problem is not solved.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's urgent, can't you give back the delete permission to resolve the emergency before investigating it?

Comment: `it's Urgent.`: This is of no concern to us. We are volunteers, questions get answered as and when people have the time and the interest to do so, sometimes never. It's also the weekend, this is usually a quiet time so answers generally take longer to arrive. Windows server 2003 is almost a year without support from microsoft you should not be using it. Why don't you just back out your changes, and then contract with someone to solve the problem for you.

Comment: I wonder if http://serverfault.com/questions/592751/removing-deny-everyone-permissions-from-gpo could be related.

Answer (score 2):

Word, Excel, etc. will create a new copy of the document and delete the original copy of the document whenever a user edits and then saves a document. For that reason a user needs the Delete permission in order to edit and save existing documents. You've applied an explicit Deny for the Delete permission to the Everyone group, so nobody can edit and save existing documents.

You need to remove the Explicit Deny that you've applied.

Comment: so there any other way ,which is using i can deny delete permission to everyone on server but they are able to modify,create,edit file .